# Subsetting rows of a dataframe when respondent number is duplicated in column

Tags: r, filter, duplicates, subset

I have a huge dataset which is partly pooled cross section and partly panel data:

```
  Year      Country Respnr Power          Nr
1 2000      France  1      1213           1  
2 2001      France  2      1234           2
3 2000      UK      3      1726           3
4 2001      UK      3      6433           4
```

I would like to filter the panel data from the combined data and tried the following:

```
> anyDuplicated(df$Respnr)
[1] 45047 # Out of 340.000

dfpanel<- subset(df, duplicated(df$Respnr) == TRUE)
```

The new df is however reduced to zero observations. The following led to the expected amount of observations:

```
dfpanel<- subset(df, Nr < 3)
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not figured out why the previous did not work, the following does provide a working solution. I have simply split the previous approach. The solution adds a column `panel`, which in my case is actually a welcome addition

```
df$panel <- duplicated(df$Respnr)
dfpanel <- subset(df, df$panel == TRUE)
```